# Does OS X Notification Center receive messages from APNS, LAN or just locally?

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm looking for technical details on how the Notification Center is architected on Mountain Lion so I can make the most use of it as a user of OS X. Specifically, does it receive messages directly from [Apple's push notification service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)? The high level overview documentation on Apple's developer site for [Notification Center mentions UDP delivery of a notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/NotificationBasics/NotificationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005947-CH3-SW1) so it seems a network trigger is provided but I can't find a reference to or example of this being implemented on Mountain Lion.

If not, can it receive messages from the local network or just from other programs that run locally on OS X?

Comment: If it doesn't receive push notifications directly, one could run a local program to listen for said notifications and trigger notification center notifications.

Answer (score 3):

It can work in a couple of ways. One, as you say, is through APNS.

Apps can also use the local notification centre to trigger a notification (you can see this in XCode when a build completes for example).

What are you trying to do? Maybe I can point you at the right document.

Comment: To give you an example with the same content: if you use twitter with the builtin option, your notifications come from outside your computer - if you were using the Tweetbot alpha, you could get notifications for the same content from Tweetbot, provided you enabled those.